# Updating 2 records in the database when it should ideally update 1

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to update a a record in a table from my service in .net core. I am pulling the record with a LinQ query and and trying to update a value for the record. There is just one unique record which is pulled by the LinQ query.

Below is the LinQ query:

```
var updateRecord = (from a in dbContext?.Refresh
                where a.Column1 == refresh.Column1 && a.Column2 == refresh.Column2 
                select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am updating a value in column8 in a table named Refresh in the code below:

```
 updateRecord.column8 = value;
 await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

There are 2 records in the table with the same Column1 value but their Column2 value is different and the LinQ query also pulls up only 1 record. So, ideally it should update just 1 record in the db. But it still updates 2 records, when it should update 1.

Can I please get help on this?

EDIT:
Below is the table Structure:

```
[Column1] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[Column2] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[Column3] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[Column4] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[Column5] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Column6] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Column7] [datetime2](7),
[Column8] [varchar](255) NULL
```

Sample Data:

```
Column8 : fc79107c-c3d0-4cec-a2ed-e79fd5dfaa85
```

Comment: Please share your table structure and sample data or the data you are trying to work with, so that your issue can be reproduced accordingly.

Comment: What is the primary key of this table? Column1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are 2 records in the table with the same Column1 value but their
> Column2 value is different and the LinQ query also pulls up only 1
> record. So, ideally it should update just 1 record in the db. But it
> still updates 2 records, when it should update 1.
>
> Can I please get help on this?

Well, based on my test and findings your query is correct and extracting the expected result, but the main issue is in `updateRecord.column8 = value;` linq cannot parse the correct subsequent SQL query and it will always considering `column1` in terms of update table row because it doesn't find the primary key and considering `column1` as primary key as a result updating the full table rows. As you can see the update log below:

[image]

Another important point is that, you have two records, so we cannot say which one is unique or different, first one or last one, so this concern remains always.

**How to resolve:**

Let's say, you have following table structure:

[image]

You can use [raw sql functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#passing-parameters) in order to resolve your issue because linq cannot parse the way you need the query to be executed. You can try following way:

SQL stored procedure:

[image]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateUniqueRecord
    @Column8 nvarchar(50)   
AS   
    UPDATE Refresh
    SET column8 = @Column8
    WHERE Column2 = (SELECT TOP 1 Column2 FROM Refresh 
                     WHERE Column2 != Column1)

    SELECT TOP 1 Column1, Column2, Column3, column8   
    FROM Refresh 
    WHERE Column2 != Column1
GO
```

Call stored procedure in controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var UpdatedValue = "New updated column value";
    var executeSp = string.Format("EXEC UpdateUniqueRecord '{0}'", UpdatedValue);
    var sqlresult = _context.Refresh.FromSqlRaw(executeSp).ToList();
    return Ok(sqlresult);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Apologies for delayed response. Thank you for the detailed explanation. It worked for me.